# Cannot disable parental controls for Admin user

Tags: macos, high-sierra, administrator, parental-controls

I wanted to put parental controls on my computer before I learned that administrator users can't have parental controls (makes sense to me now). But somehow I still managed to enable parental controls for my administrator user, and it didn't give me any warning message.

I can tell that enabling parental controls really did work because some websites are blocked. This persists even after rebooting my Mac.

[image: Website blocked by parental control]

Now I want to turn off parental controls, but I can't do it. When I try to turn it off in System Preferences, I get this error message ([video](https://i.gyazo.com/76971c617accf59059491314c831a9e8.mp4)):

> You cannot enable parental controls for an administrator account. Create a new user account, and then enable parental controls for the new account.

So how can I turn off parental control for the Admin user?

Comment: Can't try myself (for obvious reasons), but try the following: create a new admin user, log out of the old one and into the new, downgrade the old admin account to standard, disable parental control, upgrade it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to @nohillside,
I created a new admin user, loged out of the old one and loged into the new one but I was not able to downgrade the old admin account to standard, so I did [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1727847) :

```
dscl . read /groups/admin GroupMembership
```

then

```
sudo dscl . delete /groups/admin GroupMembership Anakojm
```

Then I restarted my mac and created a stantard user with the same name (Anakojm) and I get this message :

> A home folder named Anakojm already exist use it ?

Then I clicked yes and disabled parental control, and upgraded it again.